# Upload Like Normal using the jQuery-File-Upload plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-plugins

I am wanting to use the jQuery-File-Upload plugin located here https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload . I have implemented it for the most part but I am having trouble actually submitting the form. What I would like to do is when the user clicks on "Upload", instead of uploading it to a default directory on my server, I would like the page to POST so I can verify the files and then store them on my server. Is this possible to do with this plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API it looks like you should be able to set an upload handler end point using a url parameter during initialization.  I would image you could point that to a php/aspx/anything else location and handle it in there.

> The File Upload widget is initialized by calling the fileupload method
>   on a jQuery collection with the target HTML element:
>
> ```
> $('#fileupload').fileupload();
> ```
>
> The target element is usually a container element holding the file
>   upload form, or the file upload form itself, but it can also be just
>   the file input element itself, if an url is provided as options
>   parameter.
>
> The initialization method's first argument is an object that allows
>   you to initialize the widget with various Options:
>
> ```
> $('#fileupload').fileupload({
>     url: '/path/to/upload/handler.json',
>     sequentialUploads: true 
> });
> ```